# To display conversions of inch to meter. Output a blank line every 12 inches. (One meter equals approximately 39.37 inches.)

Tags: java, for-loop, netbeans-8

I am new to Java and programming itself, please excuse me if I did a grave mistake. I simply want to print a line every 12 inches. i.e after 12, 24, 36, 48 inches and so on, until 144 inches, print a line.

What I did:

```
if(i==12) 
   System.out.println();
```

But the blank line does not appear and my code just keeps on running forever.

```
public class Apple {
    public static void main(String[] args){
    double meter;
    int inch = 1;

    meter = inch/39.37;

    for(int i = 0;i <= 12 ; i++){
        for(inch =0;inch<=144;inch++){
        meter = inch/39.37;
        System.out.println(inch + "  inch =  " + meter + "  meters");
        }
        if(i==12)
            System.out.println();
            i = 0; /*To reinitialize counter so that it prints a line after each 12 inches*/
```

Comment: Please paste your complete (formatted) method

Comment: Why do you assign `i = 0` after your `if`, this is the reason why you have an infinite loop

Comment: You would do well to learn about the modulus (or modulo) operator. It has direct application in problems such as this.

Answer (score 1):

Your outer loop keeps looping for as long as `i` is less than or equal to `12`.  But once it reaches `12`, you set it to zero.  So, it is always less than or equal to `12`. That's why it keeps looping forever.

Then your inner loops all the way from 0 to 144 inches, without ever checking `i`, and therefore without printing a blank line until you have reached the 144th inch.

The way I see your code, it should be printing a blank line after `144 * 12 = 1728` inches, maybe you did not notice it?

So, long story short, you need to combine your outer `for( i` loop and your inner `for( inch` loop into one loop.

I am not going to say anymore, so as not to do your homework for you.

Comment: Actually, as I said, I am new to the concept of programming. I have started to work out by myself after learning from thenewboston.com. But I really appreciate your help. Thanks man, I will try that out.

Answer (score -1):

1. **Question**
   Print a conversion table of inches to meters. Display 12 feet of conversions, inch by inch .Output a blank line every 12 inches.(One meter equals to approximately 39.37 inches.)
2. **Explanation**
   As per question output must be displayed upto 13 feet i.e 144 inches. on Every 12 inches it prints a blank line too `if(inch % 12 == 0)`

   ```
   //13 feet = 144 inches

   double meter;
   for(int inch = 1; inch <= 144; inch++){
       meter = inch * 0.0254;
       System.out.println(inch+" inch = "+ String.format("%.2f", meter)+" meter");
       //Here am checking for every 12 inches
       if(inch % 12 == 0){
           System.out.println();
       }
   }
   ```

[This is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QF5Wd.png)